# Passing JSON to WCF via Ajax Call

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, wcf, restful-authentication

I've scoured the web for clarification for how to properly send JSON string to a WCF service.  My application has a dozen GET's, and they all work perfectly, but I cannot get the POST to get through to the debugger.  I have boiled in down to the simplest JSON string, and I still get a 400 error in the chrome browser.

Please see below,...

JS:

```
 workDataAsJson = JSON.stringify('{"TestData":"121"}');
    $.ajax({      
      type: "POST",
      async: true,
      cache: false,
      timeout: webCallDefaultTimeout,
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      url: baseUrl.concat('UpsertWorkData/' + workDataAsJson),                      
      dataType: "json",
      success: function (response, status, jqXHR) {     
        if (status == 'success') {
            var workplanData = $.parseJSON(response);                 
            // notify user of success,...

        } else {
          displayGenericModal('Web Service Error', 'Uh Oh! Unable to Connect to the Database to Obtain Work Data');
        }
      },
      error: function (response, status, jqXHR) {
          displayGenericModal('Web Service Error', 'Uh Oh! Unable to Connect to the Database to Obtain Work Data');          
      }        
  });    
  } catch(ex) {
    alert(ex);
  }
```

Now for the WCF operation contract,...

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "UpsertWorkData/{WorkData}", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    string UpsertWorkData(string WorkData);
```

Ok, now for the web.config file.  Don't laugh, I've basically thrown everything I have read at it!

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
        <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="2147483644"/>
      </webServices>
    </scripting>
  </system.web.extensions>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>
  <!--
    For a description of web.config changes see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235367.

    The following attributes can be set on the <httpRuntime> tag.
      <system.Web>
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
      </system.Web>
  -->
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength ="798778" maxUrlLength="779779" enable="true"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
      <services>
        <service name="WorkDataService.Service1">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding"  bindingConfiguration="" behaviorConfiguration="restfulBehaviour" name="ServicesEndpoint" contract="WorkDataService.IWorkDataService" />          
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>        
        <endpointBehaviors>
          <behavior name="restfulBehaviour">            
          <webHttp />

          </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="webHttpBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="200" maxStringContentLength="83886089" maxArrayLength="163841" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
       <httpProtocol>
       <customHeaders>
         <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
       </customHeaders>
   </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

HELP!! (or I gotta use node! :))

Comment: if you want to `POST`, don't put the post data in the URL, put it in `data:`

Answer (score 0):

Problem is you are trying to stringify the data which is already in string format. remove JSON.stringify

```
workDataAsJson =  '{"TestData":"121"}';
```

or

```
workDataAsJson = JSON.stringify({"TestData":"121"});
```

Also the uri should be changed as

```
  [OperationContract]    
  [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
  UriTemplate = "/UpsertWorkData",
  RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
  ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
  BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]     
  string UpsertWorkData(string WorkData);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I've tried the above and still same 400.  Keep in mind I started with creating an object and using JSON.stringify to convert it.  It's converts perfectly, but still fails on the POST.  err

Comment: keep that as it is and hceck the updated uri path in the answer

Comment: Still no go! Here is the error in the Chrome Debug,...index.html#:1 Failed to load http://localhost:12109/WorkDataService.svc/UpsertWorkData/%7B%22TestData%22:%22121%22%7D: Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 400

Comment: I encoded the workDataAsJson variable on the next line as follows:\n\n   workDataAsJson = JSON.stringify({"TestData":"121"});
    workDataAsJson = encodeURIComponent(workDataAsJson); \n\n and still no go!

Comment: `preflight` - CORS issue - CORS preflight is a `OPTIONS` request, your server doesn't handle `OPTIONS` requests - you'll need to handle `OPTIONS` requests for cross origin requests

Comment: When I try using the following url in the browser to mimick the post I get 'A potentially danger Request.Path value has been detected'.  http://localhost:12109/WorkDataService.svc/UpsertWorkData/%7B"TestData":"121"%7D

Comment: <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST, GET, OPTIONS" />
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="accept, content-type" />

Comment: I added the above to no avail.

Comment: Unfortunately the POST is still not working.  All the gets work, but the POST won't.  Even with this little bit of JSON.

Comment: look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46721952/angular-js-application-failed-to-invoke-wcf-rest-service-post-method/46761816#46761816